# how to do a two table sql select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql database with two tables A and B.  Table A has one occurrence of each value in column 1 but table B has multiple occurrences of each of the values. Something like this:

Table A

```
  alpha  zeta
+-------------+
|  abc | blah |
+-------------+
```

Table B

```
  alpha    beta
+----------------+
|  abc  | blah-1 |
|  abc  | blah-2 |
|  abc  | blah-3 |
|  abc  | blah-4 |
|  abc  | blah-5 |
+----------------+
```

What I need is a query where if there is a match in the two alpha columns (A.alpha = B.alpha) all the values of both rows are returned in the result e.g. A.***, B.*

However if there is at least one match as above but there are more 'abc' rows in table B than in table A the result rows should contain the data for each 'abc' row in table B and a row containing the single 'abc' match in table A.

So for the two tables above the result would look like this:

```
 A.alpha  A.zeta  B.alpha  B.zeta
+---------------------------------+
|  abc  |  blah  |  abc  | blah-1 |
|  abc  |  blah  |  abc  | blah-2 |
|  abc  |  blah  |  abc  | blah-3 |
|  abc  |  blah  |  abc  | blah-4 |
|  abc  |  blah  |  abc  | blah-5 |
+---------------------------------+
```

And of course abc isn't the only value in the alpha columns.

I've spent a good deal of time trying to figure this out and would appreciate any help.

Comment: The amount of time you spent to write/Fancy formatting this question, I bet if you had spend 1/10 of that time on google you would have got the answer for your question.

Comment: Most of the time (around 2 hours) I spent trying to find an answer was on Google and on the Mysql doc site.  My apologies to you if this wasn't sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A.Alpha
      ,A.Zeta
      ,B.Alpha
      ,B.Zeta
FROM TABLEA A INNER JOIN TABLEB B 
ON A.alpha   = B.alpha
```

Comment: Thanks @ToonKrijthe didnt even notice :)

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in any introduction to SQL book and is a simple join.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA 
JOIN TableB ON TableA.Alpha = TableB.Alpha
```

No magic here.